# Stop MySQL join from affecting result set

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a problem with a join that I imagine will be simple to fix (I think I'm having a brain fart).

Here is my current working query:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(journey.departure, notrelatedtoquestion) AS departure
FROM journey
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY departure
```

Here the my query that I want to work but can't get to work:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(journey.departure, notrelatedtoquestion) AS departure
FROM journey
JOIN journey_non_operation ON journey_non_operation.journey = journey.code
WHERE NOW() NOT BETWEEN journey_non_operation.date_start AND journey_non_operation.date_end
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY departure
```

Well, it is working, but the problem is that it changes the result set due to the contents of the newly joined `journey_non_operation` table.

What I am trying to achieve is very simple. I just want to filter out journeys that have today's date in the `journey_non_operation` table. But, because there are many dates of non operation for each journey, it is changing the result set.

Here are the results of the first and second queries side by side:

[image] ----- [image]

How can I stop the `journey_non_operation` join from affecting the result set, but make it so that I don't select journeys where their id is between a date of non operation?

The table structure for `journey_non_operation`:

`id` - `journey_id` - `start_date` - `end_date`

Thanks!

Comment: SO, there might be journeys whose id doesn't match any row in journey_non_operation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `not in` operator instead of a `join`:

```
SELECT   ADDTIME(journey.departure, notrelatedtoquestion) AS departure
FROM     journey
WHERE    journey.code NOT IN (SELECT journey
                              FROM   journey_non_operation
                              WHERE  NOW() NOT BETWEEN date_start AND 
                                                       date_end)
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY departure
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a LEFT JOIN and put the BETWEEN clause as part of the ON, then every match means the journey shouldn't be displayed. Therefore, you just show rows without matching records after the LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT journey.id, ADDTIME(journey.departure, notrelatedtoquestion) AS departure
FROM journey
LEFT JOIN journey_non_operation ON journey_non_operation.journey = journey.code 
     AND  NOW()  BETWEEN journey_non_operation.date_start AND journey_non_operation.date_end
WHERE journey_non_operation.id is null
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY departure
```